# Mobile site: is there a way to restrict file upload app choices?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, file-upload

I'm including file upload functionality in my site, via camera, camera roll or file manager. I've added file type restrictions to images and certain document types (word/pdf).

During testing I found that Android offers a multitude of apps (e.g. voice recorder) when the user clicks on the input element to start the file selection process. Is it possible to restrict the app choices to the above 3?

Comment: you should test the mime type in your php when accepting the upload. If it doesn't match, then throw an error message

Comment: @RachelGallen I've already imposed file type restrictions via accept ("accept="image/png, image/jpeg", etc).  I'm looking to restrict the ways a mobile user can upload a file.